# Prove the convergence of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $0 \leq a \leq b$, then $(a^n + b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $b$.

I am allowed, at this point, to use the theorem that the limit of a sum is the sum of the two limits. I'm not granted much leeway otherwise, though.

Answer (score 3):

The most natural solution is one using the squeeze theorem:

$$b=(b^n)^{1/n}\le(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}\le(2b^n)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}b$$

The left sequence is constant, hence it converges to $b$; the limit of $2^{1/n}$ is $1$, hence the right side converges to $b$. Thus the middle sequence has the limit equal to $b$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since $0<a\leq b$, we have

$${(b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\leq {(a^n + b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\leq ({{2b^n)}^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $b=0$ the result is easy. If $b\ne 0$, then
$$(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}=b\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}\right)^{1/n}.$$

We have 
$$b\le b\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}\right)^{1/n}\le b(1+1)^{1/n}\le b\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right).\tag{1}$$

Now let $n\to \infty$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}b\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=b$, by (1) our limit is $b$.